# Doughnuts preseratives

Tags: food-safety, mold

**Calcium Propionate**

I normally use calcium propionate for extended shelf life problems. I am a packed doughnuts manufacturer, and I have a problem managing my shelf life. Regarding mold on our product, I need some halal/vegan preservatives to extend my shelf life from 3-10 days. I am using yeast, baking powder, eggs, salt, and butter as an ingredients. Some authentic solutions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Early mold on commercially produced bakery goods suggests contamination, probably during the packaging process.

Answer (score 3):

I have experience with a few natural options such as [Bred-Mate](http://www.jkingredients.net/bredmate.html), [Bro-Lite](http://www.bakewithbrolite.com/) and [MoisturLok](http://www.advancedingredients.com/products/moisturlok.php), but I doubt that any of those will get you as much shelf life as calpro will. MoisturLok and Brolite both have formulations for sweet goods, and I did have luck getting yeast breads to have a 7+-day shelf life with Bro-Lite.

If you have access to it, I'd recommend just getting halal calpro, as that's going to have the longest shelf-life by far.

Answer (score -1):

King Arthur Flour sells a "cake enhancer" that extends shelf life by a few days.  It works just as well in breads and other baked goods.  The enhancer is gluten free, vegetarian, and Kosher.

http://www.kingarthurflour.com/shop/items/cake-enhancer-10-oz

Comment: The cake enhancer simply makes the bread keep soft longer. The OP is having trouble with mold, not hardening.